# URI Online Judge 1024 - Python

Tags: python, string, ascii, uri

URI 1024: Solicitaram para que você construisse um programa simples de criptografia. Este programa deve possibilitar enviar mensagens codificadas sem que alguém consiga lê-las. O processo é muito simples. São feitas três passadas em todo o texto.

Na primeira passada, somente caracteres que sejam letras minúsculas e maiúsculas devem ser deslocadas 3 posições para a direita, segundo a tabela ASCII: letra 'a' deve virar letra 'd', letra 'y' deve virar caractere '|' e assim sucessivamente. Na segunda passada, a linha deverá ser invertida. Na terceira e última passada, todo e qualquer caractere a partir da metade em diante (truncada) devem ser deslocados uma posição para a esquerda na tabela ASCII. Neste caso, 'b' vira 'a' e 'a' vira '`'.

Por exemplo, se a entrada for “Texto #3”, o primeiro processamento sobre esta entrada deverá produzir “Wh{wr #3”. O resultado do segundo processamento inverte os caracteres e produz “3# rw{hW”. Por último, com o deslocamento dos caracteres da metade em diante, o resultado final deve ser “3# rvzgV”.

Entrada
A entrada contém vários casos de teste. A primeira linha de cada caso de teste contém um inteiro N (1 ≤ N ≤ 1*104), indicando a quantidade de linhas que o problema deve tratar. As N linhas contém cada uma delas M (1 ≤ M ≤ 1*103) caracteres.
Saída
Para cada entrada, deve-se apresentar a mensagem criptografada.

Estou tentando resolver o problema do URI online judge 1024 em python, porém sempre recebo o erro "time limit exceeded". Alguém pode me ajudar a otimizar meu algoritmo?

```
n = int(input())


for i in range(n):
   string = input()
   string = list(string)
   
   for j in range(0, len(string)):
      if (string[j].isalpha()):
         string[j] = chr(ord(string[j])+3) 
      
   new_str = string[::-1]
      
   tamanho = len(new_str)//2
      
   for k in range(tamanho, len(new_str)):
      if new_str[k] == " ":
        continue
      new_str[k] = chr(ord(new_str[k])-1)
          
        
   print("".join(new_str))
```

Comment: E qual é o enunciado do exercício?

Comment: Consegue colocar uma descrição do problema? Qual exatamente é o objetivo do exercício/o que é pedido de saída do algoritmo?

Comment: ali está o enunciado.

Comment: Vc percebeu que não precisa de 3 loops? Dá pra fazer um só, que começa do final da string. Do último elemento até a metade, avance as letras 3 posições. E da metade até o primeiro, avance 2 posições (pois estes são avançados 3 e depois voltam 1)